# Execute python script in/from WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am quite new to WSO2 so maybe the question is too trivial, but as I can see it is so big, I do not know how to start.

I would like to:

1. Read some data from some sensors
2. Get this data to use on a python script.
3. Perform calculations on the script
4. Send data to sensors.

I guess I can do steps 1 and 4 with **stream processor** through http-request (at least I can read them and show them in SP editor console), but:

How do I collect the data and send it as input to the python script? Can I achieve this with Stream Processor?

Can I execute python in/from  WSO2 or should it be running apart from WSO2? If so, which componet of WSO2 shoul I use?

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I can do steps 1 and 4 with stream processor 
>   Can I achieve this with Stream Processor?

Why do you want to use wso2sp? The SP (stream processor) is intended to collect the data and create analytics, not really to invoke other services (it is possible, but not always feasible)

To process and pass data between system - you may have a look at wso2ei (Enterprise Integrator - I mean the ESB functionality).

> send it as input to the python script

The most straightforward way would be exposing your python functions as services, example https://medium.com/@umerfarooq_26378/web-services-in-python-ef81a9067aaf

An example mediation (flow) would be reading data from sensors, send them to esb for processing, the esb will call the backend python service, modify the python response to be consumable by wso2sp and send the to sp for analytics

This is just an example, we don't really know what do you want to achieve and what do you really need

In theory you may invoke an external service directly from the SP, but it may have limited capability and service options comparing to the EI

Comment: @anuf no stress :) Long story short - the most universal way to invoke the python app is expose it as a service.

Comment: As I said, I am a newbie on WSO2 so I do not have a general view off all the funcionality it offers and wich are the intentions of each module (SP, ESB, ...). I am a programmer, not a sysadmin. What I need to do is: 1) Read data from sensors (XML input/output) with WSO2 (no matter if SP or ESB) periodically. 2) perform some checks and calculations in python according some rules. 3) after calculations end, send some parameters back to sensors (SP?, ESB?) .

Comment: Sensors are attached to different locations wich have their own computer, so they can work as stand alone points and eventually send data to a central computer. Rules in step 2 may change, so I need to update then in some way in all the locations at the same time. Can I also achieve this with WSO2?